# Why isn't it possible to add RSpec stub methods to this object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

For some reason RSpec stubbing isn't available in my tests and I can't figure out why.

Here's an example test:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do 
  it "Should allow me to stub a model" do
    u = User.new
    u.stub(:test)
    u.test
  end
end
```

and here's the test result:

```
Failures:

  1) Subscription Should allow me to stub a model
     Failure/Error: u.stub(:test)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for #<User:0x007fa5cfea20c8>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) 
     in <top (required)>'
```

FWIW the mock config section of my spec helper file is as follows:

```
config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
  # For more details, see:
  #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  mocks.syntax = :expect

  # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
  # a real object. This is generally recommended.
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should use [new syntax](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) `allow(u).to receive(:test)`

Comment: @zishe yes, that's a good suggest but I've obviously got something setup incorrectly and it would be good to fix that

Comment: Looks like `mocks.syntax` should be `should`, i added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old syntax is [accessible with `mocks.syntax = :should`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/old-syntax). However, you can use new: [`allow(u).to receive(:test)`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/basics/allowing-messages)

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. I get it now, the entire syntax has changed. Right - thank you I'll address